# How does the in-application programming for ARM (Cortex M3) work?

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, cortex-m

I'm working on a custom Cortex-M3-based device and I need to implement in-application programming (IAP) mechanism so that it will be possible to update the device firmware without JTAG (we'll use TFTP or HTTP instead). While the IAP-related code examples available from ST Microelectronics are clear enough to me, I don't really understand how the re-flashing works.

As far as I understand, the instructions are fetched by the CPU from the Flash through the ICode bus (and the prefetch block, of course). So, here's my pretty silly question: why doesn't the running program get corrupted while it re-flashes itself (i.e. changes the Flash memory from which it is being run)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A common solution is to have a small reserved area in the flash, where the actual flashing program is stored. When new firmware has been downloaded just make a jump to the code in this area.

Of course, this small area is not overwritten when flashing firmware, it can only be done by other means (like JTAG). So make sure this flashing-program works good to start with. :)

Comment: Ah-ha... That's right, I've missed that part while studying the code!

Comment: Yes, however on many devices it is additionally necessary to actually be running from ram while programming the flash, so a short block of programming code must be copied to RAM and invoked to do the actual programming, even if the overall process is managed by code in a reserved portion of flash.

Comment: There are many failure scenario that you need to consider, otherwise, you might end up bricking up your system. IAP is a corner stone of f/w development and doing it right specially over lossy network can be tricky.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with STM implementation, but in NXP chips the IAP routines are stored in a separate, reserved ROM area which can't be erased by user code.

If you're implementing the flash writing code yourself by using HW registers directly, you need to either make sure that it doesn't touch the sectors it's running from, or runs from the RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Now a days many micro-controllers supporting IAP, that it is possible to program its flash memory while program execution in the same flash.

For IAP, program memory in the flash may be divided into 2 parts, one executable & other backup parts.

Generally we program the flash memory at a location (say, part-1) through JTAG, whose firmware version is 0.01. For IAP, i.e, program the flash in another part (part-2) while code is executing, corresponding API's should be provide in firmware version 0.01, which helps to program the flash part-2, After completion of programming successfully firmware version will be updated as 0.02. Upon processor restarts, program execution jumps to latest firmware by checking firmware version at initialization.

The part where the firmware is executing is called executable part, and other is back-up. why it is called back-up mean, suppose if there exists any firmware corruption while programming, firmware version will not update & upon restart, program control will automatically jumps back to back-up firmware after checking version number.

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to do it is using custom made bootloader. However STM IAP is not stored in Flash so it can not be overwritten by it self. What generally people do is to spilt the flash in two parts , one is reserved for Custom made Bootloader and Another is for application. Bootloader makes sure that it does not write to its own assigned area. Bootloader can be programmed through JTAG and later application can utilize bootloader to program itself.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand, the instructions are fetched by the CPU from the Flash through the ICode bus (and the prefetch block, of course). So, here's my pretty silly question: why doesn't the running program get corrupted while it re-flashes itself (i.e. changes the Flash memory from which it is being run)?

This is because, in general case writing/programming to flash memory is not allowed while you are reading from it(i.e executing code).

Have a look at [this](https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/tools/f/armds-forum/992/cortex-m3-execution-code-from-ram-during-flash-programming) for some ideas on implementing IAP.